# powershell invoke-command update contents of a file with multiple lines of content

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I need to update server names in a bunch of config files on multiple servers.  I have a quick script to do it, but don't want to log in to every server individually and move the script local to it just to run it.  So I'm using Invoke-Command.  Everything is working getting the contents of the files and updating it, but when I try to write the new content back to the file, I'm getting a PositionalParameterNotFound error on the Set-Content.  I assume because it's multi-line?

Here's the block of code that iterates through the files and attempts to write them back out:

```
ForEach($file in $Files){
    $content = Invoke-command -computerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {get-Content $args[0] -raw} -argumentlist $($file.FullName)
    $content = $content -replace $serverRegEx, $newServer
    Invoke-command -computerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {Set-Content -path $args[0] -value "$($args[1])"} -argumentList $($file.FullName) $content
}
```

How do I pass this multi-line content back to the remote command parameter?

Comment: this has nothing _directly_ to do with your problem ... why are you running `Invoke-Command` twice? you are pulling the content across your net, changing it, and then sending it back. a simpler & more robust way would be to put all the commands in a script block, use the `$Using:` scope to hand the $vars into the script block, and run the entire thing on the remote system.

Comment: the answer to your question has everything to do with the fact I'm a PS rookie.  Since this is a script I need to run one time on each of 10 servers, my multiple invokes would probably be enough... but I like the $using scope idea so much I'm going to try it anyway!

Comment: you really otta make as few `Invoke-Command` calls to each system as you can manage. each takes time ... and with lots of systems even a small chunk of time adds up right quick. [*grin*] plus, that "pull it to the local box, process it on the local box, and then send it back to the remote box" bit is going to be a slow down all on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is really simple here... `-ArgumentList` accepts an array of objects, but you aren't passing it as an array. Here's what you have:

```
Invoke-command -computerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {Set-Content -path $args[0] -value "$($args[1])"} -argumentList $($file.FullName) $content
```

Here is, what I believe, your intent for parameters:

```
-computerName = $computerName
-ScriptBlock = {Set-Content -path $args[0] -value "$($args[1])"}
-argumentList = $($file.FullName), $content
```

The issue is that you don't have a comma between `$($file.FullName)` and `$content`, so it does not see them as an array of objects, it sees `$($file.FullName)` as the value for `-argumentList`, and then sees `$content` as a separate object that it attempts to evaluate as a positional parameter, but it cannot determine what positional parameter it could be. The solution is to add a comma between the two items:

```
Invoke-command -computerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {Set-Content -path $args[0] -value "$($args[1])"} -argumentList $($file.FullName),$content
```

Comment: I knew it would probably be something stupid.  Thank you.  It looks like you and zdan both answered this close to the same time, but I'm marking yours as the correct answer since it appears to have come first.  That said, I think Lee_Dailey is also on to something as well.  Thank you all!

Comment: Agreed, less data transfer is better, and the `$using:` scope is also a great thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue.

You cannot use local variables in a remote session without specifying to do so. This requires PowerShellv3+ and beyond.

Example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {
   Write-Output The value of variable a is: $using:a
   Write-Output The value of variable b is: $using:b
}


Get-Help about_remote_variables -Full
```

[About Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6)

> LONG DESCRIPTION
>
> You can use variables in commands that you run on remote computers.
>   Simply assign a value to the variable and then use the variable in
>   place of the value.
>
> By default, the variables in remote commands are assumed to be defined
>   in the session in which the command runs. You can also use variables
>   that are defined in the local session, but you must identify them as
>   local variables in the command.
>
> USING LOCAL VARIABLES
>
> You can also use local variables in remote commands, but you must
>   indicate that the variable is defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope
>   modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accidentally converting an array to a string with "$($args[1])". Try this.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    ForEach($file in $using:Files){
        $content = get-Content $file.FullName
        $content = $content %{$_ -replace $serverRegEx,$newServer}
        Set-Content -path $file.FullName -value $content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Invoke-command` `argumentList` argument accepts an array, in your seconde use of `Invoke-command` you are only passing a single argument (`$($file.FullName)`) to `argumentList`. The `$content` variable gets passed as a separate argument to `Invoke-command`, not your script block.

Fix this by passing your 2 arguments as an array:

```
Invoke-command -computerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {Set-Content -path $args[0] -value "$($args[1])"} -argumentList @($($file.FullName),$content)
```